# How would I correctly parse data from wordpress mySQL DB to xamarin forms c#?

Tags: c#, mysql, wordpress, parsing, xamarin.forms

I am using the Jetpack Wordpress Plugin, which allows allows a mobile app to connect to the websites MySQL database, the data request completes successfully however it pulls all the html code with the content, all I require are the paragraphs in the content field, this is how it displays:

[image]

As you can see the image and Title appear fine, only the content pulls all the wordpress html with required text paragragh in between.

XAML File with code behind:

```
<ListView x:Name="postListView" HasUnevenRows="true" SeparatorVisibility="None">
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
    <ViewCell>
      <StackLayout Padding="10" Orientation="Vertical" BackgroundColor="#4c4c4c" Spacing="5">
        <Image x:Name="listViewImage"
               Aspect="AspectFill"
               Source="{Binding featured_image_url}" 
               HorizontalOptions="Fill"  
               HeightRequest="200" />
        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand">
          <Label
            Text="{Binding title}"
            FontSize="15"
            FontAttributes="Bold"
            TextColor="#fac80d"
            HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
            LineBreakMode="WordWrap"/>
          <Label x:Name="ContentLabel"
            Text="{Binding content}"
            FontSize="12"
            TextColor="White"
            HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
        </StackLayout>
      </StackLayout>
    </ViewCell>
  </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

Code Behind set to pull 10 blog posts:

```
  public partial class NewsPage : ContentPage
{
    private const string Url = "www.website.com"; 
    WordPressClient client;

    public NewsPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        client = new WordPressClient(); 
    }

    protected override async void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();

        var postlist = await client.GetPostList(Url, PostType.post, PostStatus.publish, 10, 0);
        postListView.ItemsSource = postlist.posts_list;

    }

}
```

Model:

```
[JsonProperty("title")]
    public string title {get; set;}

    [JsonProperty("content")]
    public string content {get; set;}

    [JsonProperty("featured_image")]
    public string featured_image_url {get; set;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to this issue, for anyone who experiences this in their project - when pulling data from a WordPress website, it will get a HTML string of data along with the theme you're using custom code, this is why HTML Agility pack was not recognizing the data as HTML, because it was full of square brackets [].

To  remove the unwanted code I used REGEX, to use REGEX :

using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

In your code you need to take your HTML content and clean it up with the following snippet:

```
var plainContent = Regex.Replace(wallItem.content, @"^?\[.*", ""); 

var cleanedContent = plainContent;

//The Webview Source HTML
HtmlWBS.Html = cleanedContent;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [HTMLAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com) to parse the HTML and extract the content that you want.

```
var doc = new HtmlDocument ();
doc.LoadHtml (content);
// use the HTML DOM to extract the data you need
var div = doc.GetElementbyId ("...");
```

This [blog post](https://blog.xamarin.com/data-extraction-in-mobile-apps/) discusses this approach in more detail.

Comment: -Thank you, I will try this approach and revert.

Comment: I've tried using the HTML Agility Pack and Regex and just can't target the text itself in each post, the issue is the format it downloads in - it's full of [square brackets] which my WordPress builder uses.

How can I get all text between [] then target all [] to be removed thereafter, but keeping text between et_pb_text module, well some of it?

Example:

[et_pb_text admin_label=”Text” background_layout=”light” text_orientation=”left” use_border_color=”off” border_color=”#ffffff” border_style=”solid”]
“I realized Yitzhak Rabin is NOT the first Jewish leader we killed!”
[/et_pb_text]